# Javascript Promise understanding

Tags: javascript, multithreading, react-native, react-native-ios

Here's my code for downloading file using RNFetchBlob in React Native.

```
  let thumbs = []
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
    thumbs.push(this.downloadThumb(this.state.thumbs[skip + i]))
  }
  Promise.all(thumbs)
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        totalCount: this.state.totalMarkerCount,
        fetchedCount: skip + count
      })
      this.recursive_thumb(skip + count, count)
    })
    .catch(reason => {
      this.recursive_thumb(skip + count, count)
      this.setState({
        totalCount: this.state.totalMarkerCount,
        fetchedCount: skip + count
      })
    })
```

I have used Promise.all for check whether downloading is finished or not.

And does this code above works like thread? or normal ?

If it's not thread, is there anyway to use Thread in React Native.

DownloadThumb function is promise function.

Comment: this code waits for all the promises in `thumbs` to resolve before calling the function in `.then` .. what is a thread in javascript?

Comment: javascript is single threaded, resource downloads can happen concurrently though as that is a different subsystem of the browser, but the then() callback is only going to be called once so there is no need for threading here

Comment: Yeah, this code waits for all the promises. I wanted this code works like multiple-thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is no waiting (i.e. blocking) a thread. The function given to `then(...)` will be called when all promises are fulfilled.

That means that, for example, `this.state.totalMarkerCount` could have a different value than it had when you called `Promise.all`.

JS in the browser is single-threaded (ignoring web workers for a moment here), that means you can't block the thread (you can try with a `while(true) { ... }` loop and see what happens ;))

Comment: Yeah, I understood but I have called downloadThumb in for loop. In fact, I thought donwloadThumb is called like thread. Isn't it true?

Comment: You could say its 'like' a thread but that would create an incorrect understanding of Promise functionality. When downloadThumbs is called a new Promise instance is created which creates the callback association to be called when its process' are done. It will help you better understand if you do not relate it with threads and look at its as organized callbacks.

Comment: downloadThumb is not called in a thread. It also just registers a callback for when data arrives and hands you a promise object, so you can register a callback for when the download is complete.